# My custom accessor is never used and only the field default value is used by hibernate validator instead

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have the following code inside a javabean:

```
@AssertTrue
private boolean addressReferenceValid;

public boolean isAddressReferenceValid() {
    if (addressType.equals(AddressType.ON_THE_FLY_ADDRESS) && StringUtils.isEmpty(addressReference)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The issue I have is that the **isAddressReferenceValid** accessor is never used and it seems that only the default value for **addressReferenceValid** is used (i.e. `false`).

I have double checked that Spring Roo did not generate its own accessor for that variable.

Can anyone please help?

***P.S.** I can't put the @AssertTrue annotation directly on the method because then the following key in `ValidationMessages.properties` file would not be resolved: `AssertTrue.familyAdvertisementSearchCriteriaInfo.addressReferenceValid`*

**edit 1**:

Full bean:

```
@RooEquals
@RooJavaBean
public class FamilyAdvertisementSearchCriteriaInfo {

    @Valid
    private FamilyAdvertisementSearchCriteria searchCriteria;

    private Address currentAddress;

    private String addressReference;

    @NotNull
    private AddressType addressType;

    @AssertTrue(groups=Default.class)
    private boolean addressReferenceValid;

    public boolean isAddressReferenceValid() {
        if (addressType.equals(AddressType.ON_THE_FLY_ADDRESS) && StringUtils.isEmpty(addressReference)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Validation occurs in the following controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/familyAdvertisementSearch", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html")
public String familyAdvertisementSearchResults(@ModelAttribute @Validated(Default.class) FamilyAdvertisementSearchCriteriaInfo familyAdvertisementSearchCriteriaInfo, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            populateModel(model);
            familyAdvertisementSearchCriteriaInfo.setCurrentAddress(memberService.retrieveCurrentMemberAddress());
            return "search/familyAdvertisementSearchForm";
        }
...
```

Comment: How do you bean validation? At which layer of your app do you want validation to occur? And what triggers the validation? Or do you validate using the Bean Validation API directly? Are there other constraint on your bean which are getting validated? Maybe you can post the full bean?

Comment: Hi Hardy! I have edited my post as requested. Yes there are other contraints as shown above. Please let me know if you need further information...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand now what you are trying to do. You want to place the constraint on the field, but during validation you expect the method isAddressReferenceValid to be called/used. That's not going to work. If you place a constraint on a field access is used to get the property to validate (using reflection). If you place it on a method/getter method access is used. So he placement of the annotation matters. As you already seem to have discovered placing the annotation on the method works. Of course this leads to inconsistent placement of annotations. You could:

- Just place the annotation for this single constraint
- switch to method annotations completely
- update the Boolean every time the address type changes (and get rid of isAddressReferenceType method)
- create a custom constraint for verifying the addressReference

Just some ideas. It all depends on your use case and personal preferences.

Comment: Btw, I don't understand you comment regarding the message interpolation problem.

Comment: `Just place the annotation on the method for this single constraint` seems to work fine. As far as the message interpolation problem is concerned, I just noticed that just using the method without the field, did not work. As for reflection being used, I was not aware of that... Thanks a lot anyway.